# Summation with conditions in for loop

Tags: matlab

I need to calculate the following in MATLAB:

[image: \tau = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j \neq i} \sum_{k \neq i,j} w_{ji}*w_{ki}*d_j*d_k]

Basically, it is a sum over a matrix but you do not include the instances where i=j and k = i or j.
I have coded this as follows:

```
for l=2:1001;
tau1(1) = 0;
for i = 1:34
    for j = 1:34
        for k = 1:34
            if j ~= i & k ~= i & k ~= j
                tau1(l) = tau1(l-1) + TecCoef1(j,i)*TecCoef1(k,i)*herf1(j)*herf1(k);
            else
                tau1(l) = tau1(l-1);
            end
        end
    end
end
end
```

The code itself is fine. However, I need to calculate this for 1000 iterations. And this is where I am having issues. I simply get 1000 zeros, most likely due to the fact that I initialised tau(1) as 0. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you tell us the dimensions of w and d?

Comment: w, aka TecCoef1 is a 34*34 matrix of non-symmetric weights. d, aka herf1 is a 34*1 vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, as mentioned in the other answers, you probably do no need the `else` clause.

In addition though, shifting the `j~=i` conditional to where it is stated in the formula (one level up) should save you a bit of computational time if you're dealing with large matrices:

```
for l=2:1001;
    tau1(1) = 0;
    for i = 1:34
        for j = 1:34
            if j~=i
                for k = 1:34
                    if k~=i && k~=j
                        tau1(l) = tau1(l-1) + TecCoef1(j,i)*TecCoef1(k,i)*herf1(j)*herf1(k);
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are always resetting `tau(l)` to `tau(l-1)` because your `else` condition will always execute when j==34 and k==34, the value of `i` is irrelevant.

I think it may fix your problem if you replace the assignment in your `else` statement with `continue`, which will just cause you to skip that iteration - or remove the `else` altogether.

For example:

```
for l=2:1001;
    tau1(1) = 0;
    for i = 1:34
        for j = 1:34
            for k = 1:34
                if j ~= i & k ~= i & k ~= j
                   tau1(l) = tau1(l-1) + TecCoef1(j,i)*TecCoef1(k,i)*herf1(j)*herf1(k);
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do something like this?

```
tau1(1) = 0;
for l=2:1001;
    tau1(l) = tau1(l-1);
    for i = 1:34
        for j = 1:34
            for k = 1:34
                if (j ~= i) && (k ~= i) && (k ~= j)
                    tau1(l) = tau1(l) + TecCoef1(j,i)*TecCoef1(k,i)*herf1(j)*herf1(k);                    
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```